# How safe is setting the firestore DB to a window object?

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack, google-cloud-firestore

I am beginning to learn programming.

I am using firebase via NPM within webpack. Within webpack firestore DB was not global so to set it as global i:

```
window.db = firebase.firestore()
```

Currently i am setting the firestore db as a global object on the window. As within webpack i have had to set the db variable on each module. Which became difficult to manage.

I just want to be sure that is a safe thing to do.

There are security rules in place for matching of UID and email to gain access, but just want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firebase` is already a global.  It won't hurt anything to make yet another global.

What you're doing here has absolutely nothing to do with security rules.  Rules only affect the queries you make.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. When i am using firestore within webpack nothing was global so i had to set it as global. So i chose the window object.